# My regex does not effective in spring-cloud-gateway

Tags: regex, spring-cloud

I'm learning spring-cloud-gateway, when I practice `predicates`, I want to try some regex like followings:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: after_route
          uri: http://www.google.com/
          predicates:
            - Cookie=token, hello*
```

I think `hello*` will matches `hello`,`helloa`,`helloaaaaa`..., but when I test by `curl --cookies ...`, it only matches `hello`, why `helloa` and `helloaaaaa` does not matches correctly?

Does regex in spring cloud application.yml need some changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doesn't have anything to do with yaml or gateway just java regex

```
"helloaaaa".matches("hello*") // returns false.
```

But this works

```
"helloaaaa".matches("hello.*") // returns true.
```

Patter [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) says `X* matches X, zero or more times`

So your regex would match "hellooooo"

```
"hellooooo".matches("hello*") // returns true.
```